# Security on MLab Access on React Frontend

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, security, mlab

I would like to render highcharts on my react frontend. The data is coming from my mlab mongodb. There is native mongodb drivers available, I dont know though, whether I can expose my password and user on the react frontend. Is there any security issues or measures I could take to prevent exposing mlab access data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No purely on frontend you cannot prevent leaking your data. So you better make requests to mlab on you backend. And store all the passwords etc. using(for example) process.env variables.